# Java actionPerformed method not setting the value for class variable

Tags: java, swing

Please help me with this. I have been stuck for hours!
I have addActionListener to my JTextField, and **inside the actionPerformed(),** I am trying to **modify one class String variable choice**. BUT IT IS NOT CHANGING! **The value of choice after the actionPerformed() method is always null.** I remove the actionListener after it one action has been performed, so I can do some selection later.

The code is below:

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package assignment;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI_V2 extends JFrame {
//Typing Area;
private JTextField txtEnter = new JTextField();
//Chat area;
private JTextArea txtChat = new JTextArea();

//Scroll
private final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(txtChat);

private String choice;

public GUI_V2(){
    //Frame Attributes
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(2000,2000);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setTitle("Menu ChatBot");

    //textEnter Attributes
   txtEnter.setLocation(20,1825);
   txtEnter.setSize(1950,100);
   txtEnter.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,45));

    //txtChat Attributes
   txtChat.setLocation(22,5);
   txtChat.setSize(1950,1800);
   txtChat.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,45));
   txtChat.setBackground(java.awt.Color.getHSBColor(0.4957f,0.0902f,1.0f));
   txtChat.setLineWrap(true);
   txtChat.setWrapStyleWord(true);
   txtChat.setEditable(false);

   //scroll Attributes
   scroll.setLocation(22,5);
   scroll.setSize(1950,1800);

   //Add Items To Frame
   this.add(txtEnter);
   this.add(scroll);

   final String name = greetings();

   txtChat.append(botSays("Hi " + name + "! Please enter the mode of operation:"
            + "\n(1) Add keywords and response"
            + "\n(2) Start chatting"
            + "\n(3) Exit the chatbot\n"));
    txtEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
           //add userInput into the txtChat
           choice = txtChat.getText();
           txtChat.append(name + ": " + choice + "\n");
           //auto scroll down
           txtChat.setCaretPosition(txtChat.getDocument().getLength());
           //set the txtEnter field to be empty
           txtEnter.setText("");
           txtEnter.removeActionListener(this);
       }
   });
   System.out.println(choice);

   //display main menu and ask for user choice


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GUI_V2();
}

private String greetings(){
    long currentHour = getCurrentHour();
    String time;
    if (currentHour < 12)
        time = "morning";
    else if (currentHour < 18)
        time = "afternoon";
    else
        time = "evening";
    txtChat.append(botSays("Good " + time + ", my name is Nova. Welcome to the HOTPOT restaurant!\n"));
    pause(1000);
    txtChat.append(botSays("First of all, may I know you name? Please.\n"));
    pause(1000);
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name:", "My master", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    return name;  
}

public static String botSays(String s){
    return "Nova: " + s;
}

public static long getCurrentHour(){
    long totalSec = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    long totalMin = totalSec / 60;
    long totalHour = totalMin / 60;
    return (totalHour + 8) % 24; //+8 because SG is GMT+8
}

public static void pause (int millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}


private void displayMenu(String name){
    txtChat.append(botSays("Hi " + name + "! Please enter the mode of operation:"
            + "\n(1) Add keywords and response"
            + "\n(2) Start chatting"
            + "\n(3) Exit the chatbot\n"));
    txtEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
           //add userInput into the txtChat
           choice = txtChat.getText();
           txtChat.append(name + ": " + choice + "\n");
           //auto scroll down
           txtChat.setCaretPosition(txtChat.getDocument().getLength());
           //set the txtEnter field to be empty
           txtEnter.setText("");
           txtEnter.removeActionListener(this);
       }
   });

}
```

}

Comment: How do you know? I see only *one* print statement - and that is in a place that runs *before* you ever click a button to trigger the listener?!

Comment: Yes. Your println statement is being called on GUI creation, **not** from within the listener. I think that you may be a little confused is all.

Comment: the "choice" variable is only ever used as a temporary variable in the listener, so it should not be a class variable.

Comment: Yup. I am so confused. I just want to get the input when the action is performed

Comment: Inside the actionPerformed method, choice is being changed, but why not the class variable

Comment: Isn't the actipn already triggiered when i type a choice in txtEnter.

Comment: The action should be triggered, but `println` is not part of your ActionListener, so the program never prints anything.

Comment: Make the `println` statement the last line of your actionlistener.

Comment: And I think you want `txtEnter.getText()`, not `txtChat.getText()`

Comment: It will print out the value inside the listener. But how do i retrieve the value to the creation of GUI method

Comment: Oh ya, forgot to modify that after chabging the code for a million times

Answer (score 0):

Your action performed is not working on txtEnter. That is why value of choice is not changing.